# Order of a non-linear autoregressive exogenous (NARX) model

Tags: statistics, regression, nonlinear-system, time-series, discrete-time

Suppose I have a non-linear autoregressive exogenous (NARX) model of the kind
$$y(k+1)=f(y(k), y(k-1), ..., y(k-s), u(k), u(k-1),..., u(k-t)) $$
where $y$ and $u$ represent respectively the output and the input of a discrete non linear system.

**Is it correct to say that the order of the NARX model is $\max\{s+1, t+1\}$**?

Here the Wikipedia link on info about the NARX model: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_autoregressive_exogenous_model

[Here](https://www.mdpi.com/2073-4441/12/3/820/pdf) is the paper which references the NARX model. See equation (1).

Comment: Let me see if I can read up, quickly enough, on what you have written here. I have a background that's not *very* far from yours, but I'm willing to stretch myself. You'll need to give me a honeymoon period to acquaint myself with this subject, but from then on I can take a look at your question, and hopefully it's not too far for me to answer or at least contribute positively in some way.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon thanks a lot! Whatever help will be appreciated!

Comment: @TeresaLisbon  what news about my question?

Comment: Ah! Yes, it is on the backburner. I have got a few more questions to complete, including one or two very long-time pending ones ($>3 months!$) so I will have to finish those and get back.

Comment: Ok thanks I hope you will able to answer for the next Monday, since I need this for my exam! Thanks a lot again!

Comment: Next Monday! Oh well, I'll give you some priority.

Comment: I tried looking everywhere! I looked up a book by Prisetley called Time seriesand spectral analysis. Then I looked at the Wiki page for the NARX model. Then I looked at a couple of papers. The papers I looked at were : "Gomm, J. B.; Yu, D. L. (2000). Order and delay selection for neural network modelling by identification of linearized models. International Journal of Systems Science" and "John D. Bomberger; Dale E. Seborg (1998). Determination of model order for NARX models directly from input-output data" (these were the best I could pick out). I summarize my observations below.

Comment: According to the papers, both $s+1$ and $t+1$ together, are called the orders of the model. So they are combined (as in, both are to be mentioned together)! The Wiki page was empty and gave me no information. According to Priestley's book, it seems that the answer IS $\max\{s+1,t+1\}$, that's what it talks about when it refers to the "order". So I need to know where you are reading from , but I think there's just so much variation in the answers, and so much scattered stuff to see! If you can edit your post and let me know where you are reading NARX from, I can help you better.

Comment: First of all, I can't thank you enough for your attention and for having employed your time to help me. I know there are no clear pieces of information on this argument on the web. Precisely I have read about the formula in my question in https://www.mdpi.com/2073-4441/12/3/820/pdf  **(look at the formula (1))**

Comment: What a coincidence that I happen to be active at the time of you writing this! Let's get this over quickly, I'm going to read the document.

Comment: I think I am ready to summarize my thoughts. I'm doing this in the comments for now. I request you to add the link that you posted, into the question post. I'm slightly fearing that the question may be closed once it's accepted, so if you give me permission to edit the post and add that link to the question, I'll do it. Once I do that, we should be okay! Until then, I'll continue summarizing my thoughts in the comments.

Comment: So this is what I'm thinking : essentially speaking, some papers refer to the *order* of a model, while others look at the *orders* of a model. In particular, some people are thinking about the number of input and output parameters *separately*, while others are looking at the number of input and output parameters in the same way. I provided references for both.

Comment: Yes you can add the link!

Comment: Thanks! I realize that I need to go somewhere now (football class, let me be honest!) so I cannot write an answer immediately. I'll insert the link right now. But I'll definitely squeeze one in once I return.

Comment: So do you think is not right to talk about that order of the model as I have done?

Comment: I think it's possible to talk about *both* notions of orders, and in this case, I think the notion of order that suits the situation better is having BOTH numbers i.e. $s+1$ and $t+1$ together, called as the model order. I'll explain in my answer, when I can write it up. I added the link, by the way. Now, we have a source, a link statement, and a reference page. Great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Definitions and citations

We have various kinds of definitions of the "order" of a (NARX/AR/ any kind of) model. These are so varied and apparently rare that frankly, I had a lot of trouble looking for them.

Let me mention what seem to be the two "central" ideas around model order(s).

- That models do not have an order, but rather *orders*. Essentially, we distinguish the amount of prior input required and the amount of prior output required.
- That models have an order which is a single number, which captures the number of previous time steps the model has to account for during regression.

Let me use examples to further my convictions. Note that I skip the notion of *delay*, which is an idea of how much dependence on previous parameters is delayed in the system. To put it more precisely, if $y(t) = f(y(t-2))$ for example, then $y(t)$ is like a delayed response by a step since $y(t-1)$ should have depended on $y(t-2)$ but did not, so the delay of the process is $1$. We ignore delay and set delay to zero everywhere. So all equations are abridged to have delay zero, and to set other parameters unnecessary to our discussion to convenient values.

- In [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0959152498000134) paper, the explicit idea of model order is discussed on the first page (or page 459 of the relevant journal) of the paper. More precisely, I slightly abridge the paper's equations to make life simpler, and present an equation and a definition :

> $$
> y(i) = f[y(i-1),...,y(i-m),u(i-1),\ldots,u(i-\theta-n)]^T
> $$
> The values $\color{red}{m \text{ and } n }$ are often referred to as the model orders.

- In [this](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00207720050165771) paper, the notion is actually extended far more. In fact, *randomness* is brought into the regression in the form of a variable $e(t)$, and the resulting model is referred to as a NARMAX model. In such a case, the model order is not just described by *two* but actually by *three* numbers. To put this in context, the relevant equation on page $2$ of the paper is :

> $$
> y(t) = f[y(t-1),y(t-2),...,y(t-n_y),u(t-1),...,u(t-n_u), e(t-1),...,e(t-n_e)] + e(t)
> $$

and the description given is :

> For fixed model order $n_u,n_y,n_e$... (page $3$)

So when randomness comes in, we have a different look on things, and the model order must then include that number $n_e$ as well.

- Now we take a look at the book "Spectral analysis of time series" by Priestley. Fundamentally speaking, the book relegates the idea of a control in the process, and also neglects linearity for extended periods. However, it is clear that it refers to non-linear model orders with the use of precisely one number. Even linear models (including ARMA) are used with a single number. For example, the model

> $X_t - a_tX_{t-1} - ... -a_{t-k}X_k = b\epsilon_t$

is referred to as a model of order $k$ (where $\epsilon_t$ includes randomness). In particular, in parts, the book makes a control a "part of the state", as I see it, so that $X_{t}$ and $u_t$ aren't considered separate, but rather $u_t$ comes as a part of $X_t$. But this is applied in non-linear models as well. For example, the model $X_{t+1} = aX_t +b \epsilon_t + cX_t\epsilon_t$ is referred to as an *order one* model, despite the fact that the randomness is taken to order $1$.

However, the book actually mentions something even better. Indeed, for certain models such as the threshold and TAR model, the idea of a "model order" actually uses the AIC (Akaike information criterion). The Akaike information criterion's Wikipedia page is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion) and it is described as a complexity number that balances the model's goodness of fit and the number of parameters. The goodness of fit, however, is a moot point for the NARX model that uses NO randomness, and therefore that particular term is actually zero. To quote from the Wiki page for likelihood functions : "Given no event (no data), the probability and thus likelihood is 1". So the point is : the order *reduces* to the number of parameters.

---

### Summarizing thoughts, and *my* answer to your question

The citations of the given source do not actually make explicit references to model orders very cleanly, or never at least as cleanly as these papers. But let me summarize my thoughts, because we've clearly seen that opinion is split.

The point is that functions can be extended to make "empty" use of their arguments. For example, consider the function $f(x,y) = x$. This doesn't even make use of the second argument, so calling it a function of two variables is correct but just feels redundant!

However, that's exactly the point. See, let's look at your model, which is :
$$
y(k+1) = f(y(k),y(k-1),...,y(k-s),u(k),u(k-1),...,u(k-t))
$$

Suppose without loss of generality that $s>t$. Then, we can add the variables $u(k-t-1),u(k-t-2),...,u(k-s)$, and let the function $f$ be the same. This is creating *fake* dependence on $u(k-t-1),u(k-t-2),...,u(k-s)$ : the truth is that like the variable $y$ in $f(x,y) = x$, they are empty and carry no meaning. When we do this, we get :
$$
y(k+1) = f(y(k),y(k-1),...,y(k-s),u(k),u(k-1),...,u(k-s))
$$

where it makes far, far more sense to say the order is $s+1$ (which equals $\max\{s+1,t+1\}$). This kind of *empty* dependence allows us to use the notion of order as *ONE* number.

Now, when is this kind of reasoning feasible? The answer is obvious : when adding the redundant variables doesn't change the context too much. When it's not too much effort. We usually measure effort in terms of "computational complexity". So, in some sense, if $s$ and $t$ are *similar* in computational order (note : I'm willing to explain what this means outside the post, but I'm keeping it imprecise inside) then one can augment the function with these additional variables, and say that the order of the given system is $\max\{s+1,t+1\}$.

> So are you correct, keeping your source in mind? *yes, you are*. Why? Because in your source, it is quite clearly mentioned that the terms $n_x$ and $n_y$ are four and three respectively, as used in the applications. See, for example page $9$ of $16$ for these details. Now,these are constants. So straight away, they are not going to explode, or have any kind of change. Therefore, it *instantly becomes reasonable* to say that the additional "waste" parameter is not going to be an computational burden in any manner, and therefore the "order" of the model can be given as $\{s+1,t+1\}$.

So when would such an idea fail? Let's say $t = s^2$. Then, calling a model with $s$ time delay and $s^2$ control delay as a model with order $s^2$ is going to look very comical because you are grossly, grossly overestimating the $s$ time delay (by a whole square root : how fast does $s^2$ grow with $s$!). In such a case, it is obvious that you are better off mentioning each parameter in separation, and calling the collective the model order.

Note also, that I have mentioned only *one* reason that the model orders should not be kept separate. There may be a plethora of reasons as to why they should be kept separate, including the fact that an increase of a single model order could lead to computational blow up of several orders. This is, in fact the case in the papers mentioned. For them, the optimization between several AR schemes of low order suggests that even among small fluctuations of input and output order, computational gaps exist that must be sorted out.

So are you right? Don't worry, you are. But there is another right, and we will acknowledge that as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your accurate answer! I will read this at least with the same accuracy used by you in helping me!

Comment: @pawel Welcome!

Comment: @L.G. I apologize. Let me undelete and then we'll discuss on how to improve the question.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I've flagged the remaining two unfriendly comments by the user you replied to.

Comment: @Saad Thank you. We had a good conversation on the other page. You can see how much of this answer you understand. Fun fact : I had no clue about this subject before I wrote this answer. Now I realize that it's actually a fascinating subject!